# Getting rid of 'grep: line too long'

Tags: grep

I used the following syntax in order to find the IP address under `/etc` (answered by Dennis Williamson on the Super User site), but I get the message

> grep: line too long

How can I get it to ignore this message and continue searching other IP addresses because the message that I get stop the IP addresses searching (maybe because binary of files?) -:(

```
 grep -Er '\<([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\>' /etc/ 
 grep: line too long
```

Is there a solution for this problem? Maybe somthing that replaces the grep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the files in your /etc/ then contain VERY long lines without linebreaks, so grep skips them.

You can try [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/) instead. With it the syntax would be

`ack -r '\<([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\>' /etc/`

Comment: I run the ./ack -r '\<([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\>' /etc/* but I not get anything why?

Comment: Hmm, hopefully, http://superuser.com/questions/185582/ack-tool-like-grep-problem helped.

Answer (score 0):

The target of the grep search probably should be /etc/hosts (i.e. not /etc/)...