# ack + tool like grep (problem )

Tags: grep

I use the ack tool to find string or IP address in file system

but please see the follwoing

why ack not find the IP = 10.45.45.130 under /etc/sysconfig/*

the IP = 1:10.45.45.130 exist under network dir in uoo file

lidia

```
./ack -r 10.45.45.130  /etc/sysconfig/*
   <not get anything?>

./ack -r 10.45.45.130  /etc/sysconfig/network/*
 /etc/sysconfig/network/uoo
 1:10.45.45.130
```

example of uoo file

```
 more /etc/sysconfig/network/uoo
 10.45.45.130
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try '`ack -a`'?

From [BetterThanGrep](http://betterthangrep.com/),

```
 -a, --all-types       All file types searched;
```

Option `-r` is not required (afaik) default behavior is recursive.
To turn off recursion you use the '`-n`' option.

Now, to check if the '`-a`' is going to help you,
Try your command with the '`-l`' option (instead of the '`-r`' option).
Then try it again with the '`-L`' option.

You will figure what is going on based on where the `'uoo`' file shows up in your search results.

Here is what happens,

```
-l, --files-with-matches
                        Only print filenames containing matches
-L, --files-without-matches
                        Only print filenames with no matches
```

So, if your file does not show up on either of these forms, you need to add in the '`-a`' option
(`ack` is more powerful than `grep` but its also a bit tricky).

Comment: Even better than -a is --text.

Answer (score 0):

By default, ack goes on whitelists of filetypes.  If ack doesn't see the file as a certain type, then it ignores it.

Ack is really a programmer's tool, not a sysadmin tool.